# Terminate whole build process tree on Cancel

Tags: google-app-engine, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Example, with these GAE build settings:

```
{
"cmd": ["c:/python27/python", "C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", "./"],
"working_dir": "$file_path",
"selector": "source.python",
"name": "Google App Engine: App Server"
},
```

When I launch this build system, here are processes connected to ST:

[image: screenshot]

When I terminate build (Tools > Cancel Build), ST terminates just top process, leaving ghost child process running:

[image: screenshot]

I need to terminate those processes by hand, or they'll still run in background, and if left unnoticed any other launch of GAE build will result in error at some point.

I run build schemes with shell (`"shell": true`), but also without shell result is same - child processes are left running in background. So, does anyone knows how to configure ST build system that will clean it's state on Cancel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this as well, so I decided that instead of using a build system, I would just open up a command prompt and let the GAE dev server run on it's own, outside of ST2. [st2-gae-python](https://github.com/bnlucas/st2-gae-python).

The plugin is a work in progress, I just got it to where I could run the GAE dev server quickly, but it works for what it was intended for so far.

```
Right-click on your app's main folder.
Select `GAE.py - Create dev settings.` to generate `.gaedevserver-settings` file.
Edit `.gaedevserver-settings` file to your needs.

Right-click on your app's main folder.
Select `GAE.py - Start dev server.`
```

The `GAE.py - Start dev server.` selection opens a command prompt that runs up `dev_appserver.py`

Comment: Thanks @bnlucas, I'll check your project. In the meantime I use this command: `"cmd": ["start", "c:/python27/python", "/path-to/dev_appserver.py", "./"]` which also starts new CLI window, and terminates as expected. Also, `start` command has "/B" switch, and if used in this case, no CLI window is launched and output is redirected to ST popup shell, but unfortunately "^Break" doesn't seem to work in this ST popup shell, so "/B" can't be used...

Comment: I'll have to look into using the `start` command. Another for making the project though was to have the settings file. If you want to clear your data store on start, you just set it in the settings to do so.

Comment: I just found out that on error CLI window exits so I can't see the trace. So this should be better then my previously posted line: `"cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "c:/python27/python", "C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", "./"]`